# How to check domain availability in specific region in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I need to know how to check if a domain name is not blocked and available in specific country i used this one

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
```

but it always throws exception.

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: `throws exception` which?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

However You can use this method

```
  public static boolean isServerReachable(String url) {

    boolean reachable = false;

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        if (huc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            reachable = true;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reachable;
}
```

Comment: Returning `false` for malformed URLs, doesn't sound like a very robust approach. And why again would you write a helper method that **hardcodes** the URL in the first place? To avoid it being re-used?

Comment: If you turn that local variable url into a **parameter**, then maybe ;-)

Comment: And just for the record: this code for sure helps with generic detection, it doesn't tell the user "why" a URL can't be reached. It could be temporarily not available for example.

Comment: it always returns false

Comment: Have you added Internet permission and what is your host address? I have tested it with http://google.com

Comment: I have turned that local variable url into a parameter. @GhostCat

Comment: You could consider passing a URL object (improves unit testing), but well, that is just a subtle detail.... and of course, "out in the field", just printing exceptions doesn't really solve issues. But there isn't a much different approach here.